# How do I get the latest Billboard charts as data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any API or plugin using which I can get the top music billboards chart's data using JS or Jquery?

I'd like to get the top 10 or so songs at any point of time.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.rapidapi.com/top-four-free-music-data-apis/amp/    This isn’t a stack overflow question... but here is a quick google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed a Google search for "Billboard chart api" and was able to come up with many options, this being the first:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/billboard-top-100

This question will probably get closed because it is obvious you put little effort in trying to solve it yourself first. For your next question, be sure to include things you have tried, why it didn't work (error messages, etc) and your minimum code that produces your issue. This will help others help you, and ensure you get an answer as quickly ass possible. The more work you put into your question, the more likely it will be answered correctly and quickly.

Comment: nope, even if he tried more he would have been downvoted. That's just how stackoverflow works. This question has an answer already here, maybe not exactly for music billboards but the end result is the same. Stackoverflow needs to implement a purgatory that will delete low effort posts automatically after 30 days without banning newbs. If the big papas are tired of seeing low effort questions they should have an option to hide posts from new users since 99% of new users ask questions that are not "worthy".